# Regex Search word with double quotes in a string

Tags: python, regex

Search words having double quotes in regex

```
def key_found(key, sentence):                   # Checks for key in sentence.
    search_string = r'\b' + key + r'\b'
    match_found = re.search(search_string, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
    if match_found is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

key = '20"x30"'
sentence = '1 Unit Lace Borders Tissue Paper 20"x30" Half Ream Recycled Unit pack 120'
if key_found(key, sentence):
    print("True")
```

Its not searching key in sentence

Comment: Why not just use `key in sentence`?

Comment: Are you trying to fish out words having double quotes, or just look up a known key against the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need such complex way of doing this, but the immediate problem (and fix) to your current code is the regex pattern itself which you are using.  It should be this:

```
search_string = r'(?<!\S)' + key + r'(?!\S)'
```

The reason why the regex pattern `\b20"x30"\b` will fail to match the input is that the boundary between `"`, a non word character, and a following space, another non word character, is *not* a word boundary.  Instead, use `(?!\S)` to detect that what follows is either a whitespace character or the end of the string (and vice-versa for `(?<!\S)`.

After just making this change, keeping the rest of your code the same, I get this output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply your solution solved my problem as well as your explanation about following problem was also great..

Comment: How can i search for a key which is followed by comma or period using existing regex for eg. `key`='Paper' `sentence`='There is Tissue Paper.'

Comment: You should open a new question at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In `def key_found(key, sentence)` do this:

```
def key_found(key, sentence):                   # Checks for key in sentence.
    match_found = re.search(key, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
    if match_found is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Also, if you don't want to ignore case :

```
if key in sentence:
    print("True")
```

As you mentioned in comment that you want exact match, use re.match for that, code:

```
def key_found(key, sentence):
  for word in sentence.split():
    match_found = re.match(key, word, re.IGNORECASE)
    if match_found is not None:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I can't use this because if two words are joined like `TissuePaper` and if i try to find `Paper` it will return `True` as well as i want to find case insensitive words

Comment: Check again, I've taken the case for exact match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply your solution is working as well

Comment: Happy to help xD